# not able to create log for spark into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, logging, apache-spark, log4j

I am trying to write a log into `HDFS` for my `Spark` execution in cluster mode. 
I am using the `log4j` properties below, but do not see any log getting generated.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=hdfs://devnameservice/acceptance/cls/data/DateAdjust1.log
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy

log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy.maxFileSize=10000
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern="eventTime":"%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[z]Z}","level":"%p","correlationUUID":"%X{UUID}","ComponentName":"%c","MethodName":"%M","applicationId":"%X{applicationId}","System-IPv4":"%X{ipAddress}","System-port":"%X{systemPort}","User":"%X{user}","Action":"%X{action}","Status":"%X{status},"Reason":"%X{reason}","Message":"%m - Counter:%X{Counter} - Pipeline:%X{pipeLine} - Stage:%X{stageType}|%X{stageName} - Step:%X{stepType}|%X{stepName}"%n
```

Comment: what error or warning message you are getting while running your application?? Please share that!!!

Comment: I am not getting any error in application log (yarn logs -applicationId ) . I am keeping my log4j property file in resource directory of my application, and overriding the default spark log4j property with the mine one . My concern is if my property file is correct and the way i am providing file path in HDFS . I am not able to see any log file in hdfs .